# document.getElementById disabled in ASP.NET site

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I found a nice site that build in `ASP.NET`. I want to try some things on it, like entering text into input field through console, with JavaScript, but it looks like it disabled. when I try to do:

```
document.getElementById("name");
```

I get `null`, on each element I try it. In the `js` files of site  I see they are using `getElementById` in the code, but somehow it's disabled for me.

Comment: It's not disabled...you're doing something wrong. Do you have an element that has an `id="name"`?

Comment: Where are you running your code? After the element? In the window `load` event? Or do you have it in the `<head>` by itself?

Comment: of course I have - its exist for 100%

Comment: [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns `null` when no match is found, so either you have no element **in the DOM** with `id="name"` at the time you're trying to query it out, or something else is going on. Without more code to see what it is you're doing, it's going to be hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use clientId. For example here is your server control

```
<asp:textbox id="txtName" runat="server/>
```

and now you want to access that with javascript then you need to do following.

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID%>").value;
```

Comment: Well my ID is - `name`, so I did :`document.GetElementById("<%=name.ClientID%>").value;` and get a result : `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'GetElementById'`

Comment: something strange, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` - but I entering data for sure

Comment: can you paste your code.

Comment: @Dima javascript is case sensitive. You are using GetElementById with G instead of 'g'.  document.getElementById("<%=name.ClientID%>").value;

Comment: I actually did : `document.getElementById("<%=name.ClientID%>").value;` but now it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`. I played with that on others site and it always worked

Comment: I think there is some thing wrong with your other javascript and that's why it is creating a problem